# Check and Change for empty or null value of column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I change column text Not Exists when it is empty or null ?

My query :

```
 Select TOP 1  ISNULL(NULLIF(DR.Name,''),'Not Exists') as Name,

   DR.Name as Name ,Coalesce(NullIf(rtrim(DR.Name),''),'Not Exist') as Name,
   Name = case when DR.Name is null then 'Not Exists' 
   when DR.Name='' then 'Not Exists' else DR.Name  end 
   from Transfer TR 
   join Driver DR on DR.OID=TR.DriverID 
   WHERE TR.TruckID=51 AND  TR.Statues<>7 and  TR.DateScheduled<GETDATE()
   AND TR.DateScheduled>=DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()) ORDER BY TR.OID DESC
```

Result :
 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a single column, then you can use a sub-select, this way when no rows are returned by the query you will still get `not exists`:

```
SELECT  Name = ISNULL(( SELECT  TOP 1 NULLIF(DR.Name,'')
                        FROM    Transfer AS TR 
                                INNER JOIN Driver AS DR 
                                    ON DR.OID = TR.DriverID 
                        WHERE   TR.TruckID = 51 
                        AND     TR.Statues <> 7 
                        AND     TR.DateScheduled < GETDATE()
                        AND     TR.DateScheduled >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) 
                        ORDER BY TR.OID DESC), 'Not Exists');
```

If you need multiple columns then you could union your `Not Exists` record to the bottom of the query, place all this inside a subquery then select the top 1 again, ensuring that your actual value takes precedence (by adding the column `SortOrder`):

```
SELECT  TOP 1 Name, SomeOtherColumn
FROM    (   SELECT  TOP 1 
                    Name = NULLIF(DR.Name,''),
                    SomeOtherColumn,
                    SortOrder = 0
            FROM    Transfer AS TR 
                    INNER JOIN Driver AS DR 
                        ON DR.OID = TR.DriverID 
            WHERE   TR.TruckID = 51 
            AND     TR.Statues <> 7 
            AND     TR.DateScheduled < GETDATE()
            AND     TR.DateScheduled >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) 
            ORDER BY TR.OID DESC
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  'Not Exists', NULL, 1
        ) AS t
ORDER BY SortOrder;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but if you are trying to catch nulls and empty strings "in one go", try this:

```
select TOP 1 
case when length(trim(coalesce(DR.Name, ''))) = 0 then 
      'Not Exists' 
else
      DR.Name
as Name
....
```

The `coalesce` catches the `NULL`s and sets a replacement value. The `trim` gets rid of any padding and the `length` checks if what is left is an empty string --> so this covers nulls, padded- and non-padded trivial strings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the value has regular spaces, the following would keep your approach:

```
Select TOP 1 ISNULL(NULLIF(ltrim(rtrim((DR.Name))), ''), 'Not Exists') as Name,
```

I would probably go with the more explicit:

```
select top 1 (case when ltrim(rtrim((DR.Name)) = '' or DR.Name is null then 'Not Exists'
                   else DR.Name end) as Name
```

Unless you also wanted the spaces removed from `Name` in the output.

If you have other characters, then you can use `ASCII()` to find them.  Something like:

```
select ASCII(LEFT(DR.Name, 1))
. . .
where LEFT(DR.Name, 1) NOT LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9 ]'  -- you can expand this list of allowed characters
```

Comment: My SQL Server 2008 R2 has not trim function.Do you mean Rtirm ?

Comment: @Mhmt . . . Hmmm, the documentation says it was introduced in R2 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634558(v=sql.105).aspx).  In any case, `ltrim()` and `rtrim()` are available.

Comment: I tried ISNULL(NULLIF(ltrim(rtrim((DR.Name))), ''), 'Not Exists') as Name.Result is here  http://pasteboard.co/1N9XnTXS.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are not actually looking for a way to replace an *empty string* with 'Not Exists', but an empty result set.

In other words: It looks like you are looking for a way to show 'Not Exists' in case your query returns no rows. If it is this what you are looking for, then first "add" a 'Not Exists' record to your result set and then show the best row, i.e. the desired row in case such a row exists, else your 'Not Exists' row.

```
select top 1 name
from
(
  select name, tr.oid
  from transfer tr 
  join driver dr on dr.oid=tr.driverid 
  where tr.truckid=51 and tr.statues<>7 and tr.datescheduled<getdate()
  and tr.datescheduled>=dateadd(day,-7,getdate())
  union all
  select 'Not Exists', -1
)  
order by oid desc;
```

I chose -1 for the dummy OID. It must be a value smaller than any real OID. So if you have negative values, make that value even smaller.